# Get ID from getAttribute of descendant tag by traversing <tr id > then to td and then input tag to get its id

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried  many ways some of them works fine in chrompath extension but not in script tried this xpath as well

```
//table[@id = 'level3InnerTable_1']/tbody/tr[@id = 'Billable Client']/td[1]/input
```

I can't use input id because it's dynamic. I Want to get id of input tag by starting traversing from ID of `<tr>` i.e `Billable Client`

I am using selenium java Eclipse with Chrome

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?

Comment: Xpath is not working in any formate .want to get this dynamic  id="SelectionCheckboxInner-0"    starting from static id of <tr>="Billable Client"

Comment: *not working* doesn't mean much. What happens when you try it? if you have an exception post the stuck trace.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@id = 'level3InnerTable_1']/thead/tbody/tr[@id = 'Billable Client                                                 ']/td[1]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of `id` attribute induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibilityOfElementLocated`() and following xpath options.

> XPATH 1:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[contains(., 'Bilable to Client')]/preceding::input[1]"))).getAttribute("id");
```

OR

> XPATH 2:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//td[contains(., 'Bilable to Client')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/input"))).getAttribute("id");
```

OR

> XPATH 3:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[@id='level3InnerTable_1']//tr[@id='Billable Client'][.//td[.//input]]]//input"))).getAttribute("id");
```

Note: If you get timeout exception from all them then check if there any iframe on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value of the *ID* attribute of the `<input>` tag referencing the `<tr>` tag with *ID* value as **Billable Client** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("tr#Billable Client>td>input.selectedrow[name*='chk']"))).getAttribute("id"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//tr[@id='Billable Client']/td/input[@class='selectedrow' and contains(@name, 'chk')]"))).getAttribute("id"));
  ```